# How to longPress on TextInput to trigger one event while press to trigger editing TextInput value?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a list, and the title of the list item is actually a TextInput, so it can be easier to edit the title. Also, I want to show an options list when list item is long pressed, I want this also includes long pressing on the TextInput.

Many people said, I should add `pointerEvents="none"` to TextInput, but this will also prevent editing the value, and that's not what I want.

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work when long pressing on TextInput itself, and this is the problem that I want to solve.

```
<ListItem
  onLongPress = {onLongPressed}
>
  <Text>{Num}</Text>
  <TextInput
    placeholder="Enter title..."
    defaultValue="Title"
  />
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus`

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.state={
        edit: false
    }
  }
...
  onLongPressed = () => {
     this.setState({ edit: true }, () => this.textInput.current.focus());

  }

  <ListItem
      onLongPress = {this.onLongPressed}
      title={
        <View style={styles.titleView}>
          <Text>{Num}</Text>
         <TextInput
           ref={this.textInput}
           placeholder="Enter title..."
           defaultValue="Title"
           editable={this.state.edit}
          />
        </View>
      }
    />
```

Comment: @BahtiyarAhmatjan  If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?